# Por qué al desactivar el DEBUG en Django, ya no se reconocen los archivos estáticos

Tags: python, django

¿Por qué al desactivar el `DEBUG` en **Django**, ya no se reconocen los archivos estáticos, como los **CSS**, **imágenes** o **JS**? Lo desactivo para que salgan las páginas de error personalizadas, pero al desactivar el `DEBUG`, todos los estilos se quitan. Les agradecería mucho, si me dijeran qué me falta, o qué estoy haciendo mal.

En el archivo `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost"]
```

En el archivo `views.py`:

```
def handler404(request):
    return render(request,'error/404.html')
```

Answer (score 7):

Cuando desactivas `DEBUG`, Django dejará de manejar los archivos estáticos. En ese caso lo debe hacer tu servidor de producción.

Para poder mostrar tu página de error personalizada, debes crear una plantilla llamada `404.html` y ubicarla en la raíz de tu directorio de plantillas.

Aquí encuentras información más detallada:

- [The Http404 exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception)

Comment: La pagina de error personalizada si aparece, pero los estilos se quitan, cuando regreso el DEBUG = True los estilos regresan pero la pagina de error personalizada ya no

Comment: No es necesario que el archivo `404.html` esté en la raiz si está usando un handler customizado

Answer (score 4):

Si estás en la etapa de desarrollo no deberías tener que mover `DEBUG` a `False` a menos que ya tengas configurado un Web Server localmente tipo Nginx o Apache para servir tus archivos estáticos.

Por esta razón es que existe toda una entrada en la documentación para [servir archivos estáticos durante el desarrollo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

El problema por el que no puedes ver la página `404.html` o `500.html` es que Django está preparado para mostrarte los errores en modo de depuración (`DEBUG=True`) para ayudarte a encontrar errores en tu proyecto y mostrarte el `URLconf` en el caso de un `404`. Cuando ocurre un `404` Django llama a la función [page_not_found()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view), cuando ocurre un `500` Django llama a la función [server_error()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view).

En tu caso, estás reemplazando el [`handler404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#handler404) para que, en vez de llamar a `page_not_found()`, llame a tu propia función:

```
def handler404(request):
    return render(request, 'error/404.html')
```

Para que realmente esto funcione no basta con crear la función en tu `views.py`, también debes decirle a Django que use este handler en tu `urls.py`:

```
handler404 = 'views.handler404'
```

Pero, incluso habiendo hecho esto, Django te seguirá mostrando la página de depuración ya que te encuentras en `DEBUG=True`, lo que puedes intentar es modificar tu `urls.py` para poder rutearlo manualmente (solo en desarrollo):

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^404/$', 'views.handler404'),
        url(r'^500/$', 'views.handler500'), # Si la tuvieras
    ]
```

De esta forma, podrías ingresar en tu explorador URLs como:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/404/
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/500/

Y con esto podrías ver como van quedando tus templates.

Answer (score 3):

El método `django.contrib.staticfiles` no es suficientemente seguro para ser usado en producción, si quieres servir los archivos en producción debes seguir los pasos que mencionan [acá](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/).

En resumen, debes correr el comando `python manage.py collectstatic`, eso va a poner los archivos en el folder `STATIC_ROOT` y ejecutar los pasos posteriores, dependiendo de tu configuración, usualmente recomiendan usar S3 o un servicio para archivos estáticos, o dejar al menos que Apache o tu Web Server se encargue de eso y no Django.

El error que tienes con las template es diferente al de archivos estáticos, la respuesta de Javier es correcta, pero la causa del error es diferente, como describen [acá](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/error-reporting/), cuando `DEBUG` es `False` Django no usa las páginas de error por defecto y espera que escribas tus propias templates.

Answer (score 1):

Es innecesario que uses una función para llamar a tu página de error personalizada. Ya te dijeron antes, simplemente creas una plantilla para ese error y la pones en la carpeta de plantillas y listo, Django encontrará por si mismo la plantilla y la pondrá en lugar de la que tiene por defecto.

Puedes incluso crear una plantilla base y unas plantillas hijas para cada error sin tener que agregar funciones o urls.